# Adding of 3rd variable into data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently working on a dashboard in RStudio and run into a little issue with the creation of the data frame. Basically, I have the following variables - Countries, population by age group, and year. Currently my data frame looks like the following:

|  | Canada | China | Norway | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Under 12 Years Old | xx* | xx | xx |  |
| 12-17 years old | xx | xx | xx |  |
| 18-24 years old | xx | xx | xx |  |
| 25-34 years old | xx | xx | xx |  |
| 35-44 years old | xx | xx | xx |  |
| 45-54 years old | xx | xx | xx |  |
| 55-64 years old | xx | xx | xx |  |

*xx refers to the total population of the particular age group in each country

However, I'm having an issue adding the Year Variable in (1990, 1991, 1992 ... 2020, 2021). I do have the breakdown of the population by year but in my current data frame, I've to sum all the years for each individual country.

Could anyone enlighten me on how I can add in the year variable into the data frame such that I would be able to query from the data frame easier according to all 3 variables (e.g. the number of population for 55-64 years old for Canada from 1998 to 2008)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: A standard "long" format for you data would have 4 columns: Country, Year, Age Group, Population. Is that the answer you're looking for? We can't really tell you how to write code to add the year variable to your data frame when you don't show us the starting format, only the unsatisfactory result...

Comment: If you want to learn how to think about these things, [this description of "tidy data" is a good place to start](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org).